# How to rotate text in tm_credits

Tags: r, tmap

I want to rotate the text of the tm_credits by 90 degrees, but tm_credits doesn't have an option to rotate.
The default horizontal credits disturb the map so I want to place it along the left border of the map.

An alternative of adding a simple text (i.e., not tm_credits) will also be fine for my needs.

A simple example of what can be done:

```
data(World)
tm_shape(World) +
tm_fill("well_being", id="name", title="Well-being") +
tm_format("World") +
tm_credits("SOME CREDITS HERE", position=c("left", "bottom"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question!
From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/2.3/topics/tm_credits) I think is clear that **tmap** does not provide the option to rotate the credits. So please consider reporting this as an issue in the github repo.

May be you can achieve you what you want using the [tm_text](https://rdrr.io/cran/tmap/man/tm_text.html) function. This function creates labels for a shape object, therefore, you will have to create an additional spatial object (one LINE!). Please notice that the **along.lines** argument in tm_text let you place the label in lines along the spatial lines.

Hope it helps.